# How to correct the error of invalid transaction stop that occurs in the transaction?

Tags: postgresql, transactions, plpgsql

I have to make a PostgreSQL code to simulate a money transaction between a client of a bank 1 and a client of a bank 2. But I have an invalid transaction's termination error that I do not understand.
I have to write a SQL transaction that transfers money from a client’s account in Bank1 to another client’s account in Bank2, ensuring that the transaction handles possible errors and maintains the integrity of the data.
Here is my code :

```
--The two following commands could be grouped but, for lisibility, are not
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bank1_clients, bank1_accounts, bank1_transactions;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS bank2_clients, bank2_accounts, bank2_transactions;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank1_clients
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank1_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client int,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES bank1_clients(id),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank1_transactions
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    amount float
);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank2_clients
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    name varchar
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank2_accounts
(
    id int PRIMARY KEY,
    balance float,
    client int,
    FOREIGN KEY (client) REFERENCES bank2_clients(id),
    CHECK (balance >= -500)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS bank2_transactions
(
    id serial PRIMARY KEY,
    amount float
);


INSERT INTO bank1_clients VALUES (10, 'Client 1');
INSERT INTO bank1_clients VALUES (14, 'Client 2');

INSERT INTO bank1_accounts VALUES (8, 2000, 14);
INSERT INTO bank1_accounts VALUES (12, 650, 10);

INSERT INTO bank2_clients VALUES (25, 'Client 3');

INSERT INTO bank2_accounts VALUES (2, 300, 25);


BEGIN;
DO $$
DECLARE
    payer integer := 10; --payer referenced by bank1
    recipient integer := 25; --recipient referenced by bank2
    amount float := 10000; --amount to transfer
BEGIN
    -- Attempt to execute a query that might fail
    UPDATE bank1_accounts
        SET balance = balance - amount
        WHERE client = payer;
    UPDATE bank2_accounts
        SET balance = balance + amount
        WHERE client = recipient;
    INSERT INTO bank1_transactions (amount) VALUES (amount);
    INSERT INTO bank2_transactions (amount) VALUES (amount);
EXCEPTION WHEN others THEN
    RAISE NOTICE 'An error occurred: %', SQLERRM;
    ROLLBACK;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
COMMIT;
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: you have no table `clients` in your code, soyou have no table you can reference

Comment: Rather unusual data model, why would you create different tables for debit and credit accounts? Using just one table for all accounts, would give you the option to execute just one UPDATE to set the correct balance for both. I would fix this data model first.

Comment: Thank you. But I am a student and I have instructions.

Comment: I modified my code (but there is still approximately the same data model).

Comment: Can you help me, please (only for the syntax error) ?

Comment: Finally, I managed to correct my syntax error but got another error in exception handling.

Comment: How do you expect to get help resolving an error when you do not tell what the errors. Please post the full complete error message as text - **no image**. Further it would a benefit for you to take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and, read [ask], and [how to ask homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) questions.